# Is it possible to create an account using RPC calls?

Tags: cleos, rpc, create

### Is it possible to create an account in mainnet using RPC calls?

First, I built EOSIO nodeos in my own remote server, and I successfully created my coworker's account using **cleos**.

```
$ cleos system newaccount <MY ACCOUNT> <COWORKER's ACCOUNT> <owner-publickey><active-publickey> --stake-net "0.1 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 4
```

Now, I went on to create an account using RPC call for my web service.

However, there is not **system** api available from [developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference).

I went on to search a bit deeper.

As I felt a bit frustrated, I decided to test this [eosjs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) library to make a new account using one of [the Block Producer's public API endpoints](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/), and it worked!

The source code is like this.

```
// Configure BP httpEndpoint and chainId
const config = {
  chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906', 
  keyProvider: ['MY PRIVATE KEY'],  
  httpEndpoint: 'https://api.eosnewyork.io:443',
  verbose: false, // API activity
  broadcast: true,
  sign: true,
  expireInSeconds: 60
}

// Create a client
const eos = Eos(config)

// Make a transaction to create a new account
eos.transaction(tr => {
  tr.newaccount({
    creator: 'myaccount',
    name: 'coworker's account',
    owner: pubkey,
    active: pubkey
})

  tr.buyrambytes({
    payer: 'myaccount',
    receiver: 'coworker's account',
    bytes: 8192
})

  tr.delegatebw({
    from: 'myaccount',
    receiver: 'coworker's account',
    stake_net_quantity: '0.1000 EOS',
    stake_cpu_quantity: '0.1000 EOS',
    transfer: 0
  })
})
```

**I wonder how could this be possible?
I believe eosjs library uses https APIs, right?
Is there something I am missing?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you asking how to use eosjs?

Comment: @TeeAttack42 I am asking making a new account using eosjs works well. But, how? because there is no HTTP api that is available to request to make a new account.

Comment: when you use cleos, you can do this, cleos --print-request --print-response system newaccount, and you will find all the requests send to the node, the command will send many requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it is possible.** The *eosjs* library uses the HTTP-RPC Endpoints you mentioned aswell.

The RPC calls to look at are the [`push_transaction(s)`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transaction) calls.

For standard actions like `buyrambytes, newaccount and delegatebw` the *eosjs* library has implemented some "shortcuts". The library will build a transaction containing the action and build the required JSON structure with signatures and block infos which will be pushed to the chain ( or endpoint you defined).

The required data will be the JSON-Body of the HTTP request and will look something like this.

```
{ 
 expiration: 1,
 ref_block_num: 1,
 ref_block_prefix: 1,
 max_net_usage_words: 1,
 max_cpu_usage_ms: 1,
 delay_sec: 1,
 context_free_actions: [ '' ],
 actions: [ "create account" ],
 signatures: [ keys ],
 context_free_data: [ '' ],
 transaction_extensions: '' },
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate for taking the time to explain in detail.

Comment: @JayBKim No problem. If this answer does satisfy your question please mark it as accepted so others will find it aswell.